# Do I have to write the initialization list in both declaration and implementation of a function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, declaration, implementation, initializer-list

```
class Zb{
      int zbr;
      int* kos;
public:
      Zb(int er):zbr(er);
};
```

That was the function declaration, does its implementation have to have the initialization list as well?

```
Zb::Zb(int er):zbr(er) {
      kos = new int[zbr];
}
```

I know I could write the whole c'tor in the initialization list, but I just wanted an example that suits my question...

Comment: This constructor declaration is invalid. Your compiler should have told you so. Did you not try with your compiler, or did your compiler actually accept it for some reason?

Comment: I doubt whatever you have done works. Did you run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initialization list only belongs to the definition (that is, the actual function code).

Your code is invalid, no compiler will allow you to specify the initialization list in the function declaration.

Your code would look like:

```
class Zb {
      int zbr;
      int* kos;
public:
      Zb(int er);
};
```

And the definition (the cpp file) would look like:

```
Zb::Zb(int er) : zbr(er) {
      kos = new int[zbr];
}
```